# Baked texture comes out wrong. (distorted and in two images)

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

This is extremely confusing for me, so I apologize if I'm not very good at explaining it, but basically what happens is that whenever I try to bake this model's texture:

[image: model before baking]

It ends up doing this:

[image: baked texture 1]
[image: baked texture 2]

Two images! I have no idea of why it not only overwrites the active image, but the one being used in one of the object's materials as well, not to mention they're incredibly distorted, they don't look anything like they should.
When I try to load them, they end up looking like this:

[image: resulttexture1]
[image: resulttexture2]

I'm completely clueless as to what could be causing this, the rendered model looks perfectly fine and the UV map looks pretty decent as well.

[image]

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: triangulate your model to avoid distortions. Make sure you have the same image selected in both of your materials to bake ithe textures on the same image. You can share your file if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly it didn't work, the problem is that the baking process for some reason also targets an image that isn't even highlighted (aperturelogo.jpg as seen in image #3) when the whole texture should be in the one that is (Baking.001 in image #2).

Comment: can you share your file? It might be easier to see where the problem is

Comment: Yeah, sure.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vAhLhZq1xWiat4uvLsRaYhFTa1s_xYYp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the textures are distorted because you didn't make a good unwrap of your model. You can see using a color grid texture how distorted it is, which means you forgot to put seams somewhere
[image]

here is how it looks when fixed. You can probably make an even better job than this
[image]

For the baking part, I duplicated the model and removed all the materials but the one used for the bake, then check selected to active in the baking options with a little bit of extrusion

[image]

Then select the model wiht all the materials, and finally the one that will get the texture baked onto

Here is how it looks when baked (left is baked, right is before)

[image]

I used a wood texture because you didn't save the images in the file you sent

Hope that helps

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Comment: okay, i tried doing exactly as you said, but the issue still persisted!
in the end, i just grabbed your file and tried re-baking your texture without changing anything, and surprisingly, not even that one baked correctly.
could it be a glitch with my blender client rather than me doing something wrong?
i recorded it below because i thought it'd be easier than explaining it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VIAzjNnMb4a_UfN3i21vZwUuVCXACTVO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: both models need to be at the exact same place. I moved them so you could see the result better, sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: oh, thanks for replying, i'll try that